# Not getting the correct location of search control in tableview on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `CGPoint` to get the location of the control in `tableview` with `indexPath`. It is working fine with iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6s, but it's not giving proper coordinate with iPhone 4s. Please provide solution where I am wrong.

I am using following code:

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(CustomSearchBar *)searchBar
{ 
    CGRect cellRect =[self.tblFormDetail rectForSection:searchBar.indexPath.section];

    CGPoint origin=[self.tblFormDetail convertPoint:cellRect.origin fromView: self.tblFormDetail];
    CGPoint originView=[self.view convertPoint:cellRect.origin fromView: self.tblFormDetail];

    NSLog(@"origin from tbl %f",origin.y);
    NSLog(@"origin from view %f",originView.y);

    pointScroll=self.tblFormDetail.contentOffset;

    pointSizeScroll=self.tblFormDetail.contentSize;
    [self.tblFormDetail setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.tblFormDetail.frame.size.width,pointSizeScroll.height+originView.y)];

    [self.tblFormDetail setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, origin.y)animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Does `[searchBar convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblFormDetail];` make any difference ?

Comment: Explain your view hierarchy and explain what you want to convert from and convert to. I ask because some of your `convertPoint` calls use the same view so it isn't clear what conversion you want.

Comment: No I have added search bar in tableview cell and when i click on this then i want to get point where i click , for showing the one other table for select records .  i table number of diffrent diffrent controllers

Comment: Thanks @Zhang Your solution is working .

Comment: Thanks to all for support